# How to compare deployments in two different sandboxes of netsuite ?

Tags: netsuite

So we have done this release on one of the sandbox and other one doesn't have it. The sandbox with the release is broken and other is working fine.

We tried rolling it back but it's still breaking for vendor bills. Is there anyway to compare two different deployments in netsuite ?

Comment: You can probably use some IDE intelligence like eclipse to pull all the scripts in the deployed bundle and cross-verify the changes against the server scripts.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to compare? A single Script Deployment record? A single source file? A deployment of an entire bundle?